# header("Location: $value"); wont redirect... Why?

Tags: php, redirect, header

After login I want to send users back to `$value`,

`$value` is generated with my code, printed and looks ok.

It's a complete URL: `http://example.com/page.php?id=6`,

but it ignores the `header("Location: ".$value);` statement:

```
if($iniciando->iniciar()) {
    if (isset($_SESSION['redirect'])) {
        $he ="http://funcook.com" . $_SESSION['redirect'];
        mostrar_notificacion($he);
        header("Status: 301");
        header("Location: " . $he, true, 301);
    } else {
        imprimir_sesion_iniciada();
    }
} else {
    imprimir_formulario_sesion();
}
```

Comment: Maybe show the full code. Do you do a `die()` afterwards?

Comment: Have you printed anything before this code? Try exit(); after the header()

Comment: `die` after `header` isn't required for redirection to work. Turn on errors and you'll probably get a headers already sent warning as Matt suggested.

Comment: If possible, try using 'curl --head http://yoursite.com' or using LiveHTTPHeaders (an addon for Firefox). They're pretty helpful when debugging, and they'll show the redirect within the headers.

Comment: can you explain me how to try the curl option?

Answer (score 2):

`header("Location x");` has to be called before any other output is sent to the browser.  This includes any spaces outside the `<?php` and `?>` markers.

Also, make sure you also don't have any print/echo statements for debug purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're using Chrome?

You should use a better redirect code for all browsers to follow it:

```
    header("Status: 301");
    header("Location: ".$URL, true, 301);
```

Comment: I am having an issue with Chrome following `header();` redirects. Your answer here might be applicable, if you could elaborate a bit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8012279/why-does-chrome-cancel-302-downloads