# Why Does Chrome Cancel 302 Downloads?

Tags: php, google-chrome, redirect, header

**Edit:** After addressing some issues that may or may not have been causing problems, further testing revealed that the affected users are unable to download files, even directly. That has prompted [this question on Webmasters Stackexchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21658/what-could-keep-chrome-from-downloading-files). I am accepting the answer that seems likely to have fixed the problem, were it all about the redirection.

---

I have a [script](http://pastebin.com/SBEwBuVz) which processes downloads for my subscription-based video site. Basically, the script checks session and/or IP against the database to identify the user, and then checks the requested video file against the database to verify that the user should have access. Based on the results of these checks, the script uses `header('location: [blah]');` to either send the user to the file or to send them to an error page.

Everything works fine in IE, Firefox, and some instances of Chrome. In other instances of Chrome, users see the downloads fail completely. I have found that for these users, Chrome is automatically cancelling the 302 redirect made by the `header();` call, preventing the file from downloading.

Why is this happening? What can I do about it?

---

Edit: Here are the raw headers, as seen from Fiddler on a machine that failed the download.

**Request:**

```
GET /download_video.php?t=Nodeg004&format=wmv HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysite.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://www.mysite.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6847
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: phpbb3_cmviy_u=698; phpbb3_cmviy_k=; phpbb3_cmviy_sid=0c2fd249ff50c922beb1c7f88437c283; style_cookie=printonly; __utma=174624884.1269868282.1272079241.1320418809.1320423695.199; __utmb=174624884.5.10.1320423695; __utmc=174624884; __utmz=174624884.1319811247.179.134.utmcsr=facebook.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/l.php
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Date: Fri, 04 Nov 2011 16:22:05 GMT
Server: Apache
location: http://www.mysite.com/videos/zh4ZcnzIWJpni8tG5CzG/Nodeg004.wmv
Content-Length: 0
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

**Request:**

```
GET /videos/zh4ZcnzIWJpni8tG5CzG/Nodeg004.wmv HTTP/1.1
Host: www.mysite.com
Connection: keep-alive
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.874.106 Safari/535.2
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Referer: http://www.mysite.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6847
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
Cookie: phpbb3_cmviy_u=698; phpbb3_cmviy_k=; phpbb3_cmviy_sid=0c2fd249ff50c922beb1c7f88437c283; style_cookie=printonly; __utma=174624884.1269868282.1272079241.1320418809.1320423695.199; __utmb=174624884.5.10.1320423695; __utmc=174624884; __utmz=174624884.1319811247.179.134.utmcsr=facebook.com|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/l.php
```

**Response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 04 Nov 2011 16:22:05 GMT
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Wed, 28 Sep 2011 13:28:50 GMT
ETag: "180cc25a-5700e91-4ae005f5ce880"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 91229841
Keep-Alive: timeout=10, max=30
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
```

Comment: It may be helpful to include the full HTTP response you are sending in your question.  Also, I'm not clear on what Chrome is doing; I know it's not downloading the file but what does the user see instead?

Comment: FYI, your script is **wide open** to SQL injections.  You will be hacked, if you haven't already.  You should learn PDO with prepared queries.  At a minimum, escape your data with `mysql_real_escape_string()`.  I'd also recommend taking your actual domain out of your pasted script, so 100 StackOverflow script kiddies don't bombard you.

Comment: I linked to an almost complete copy of the script. The http response is as generated by a call to `header();` -- e.g. I'm not otherwise modifying it. The users who are not getting the file see absolutely nothing - the download link seems as if it is completely dead.

Comment: Fire up a copy of Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) and paste the full response headers here, as suggested by @SamuelEdwinWard.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for the notes there. You're right that this was too trusting of the SERVER_ variables. I'll adjust that accordingly, and have removed the domain from the code. Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: Headers added. Thanks for educating me about the existence of fiddler2!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather surprisingly, the problem seems to be that you are sending a 'location' header instead of the standard 'Location' header.
I did a quick test that seemed to confirm this, but I still couldn't believe it, so I did a quick web search and found [someone else](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=20487742179ee328&hl=en) confirming that Chrome is indeed such a stickler that it won't accept an HTTP header with the wrong case. 
A [comment](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php#79028) on the PHP manual mentions IE7 having the same quirk.

Comment: This gave me a lot of hope. But, alas, with the header sent as "Location:" instead, it still gives the same performance. I verified that Chrome is seeing the case difference, so the change is taking - just not enough...

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and accept this answer after all. There's something else going on besides the redirect issue, as one of the effected users just tested and found that he couldn't download the file even with a direct link.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [php.net comments](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.header.php#90050) and [my response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4686953/headerlocation-value-wont-redirect-why/4686976#4686976) on stackoverflow:

> Chrome doesn't perform a Location: instruction unless it gets a Status: first.  It's also sensitive to capitalisation.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. I didn't realize the Status was that much of a requirement for Chrome. Unfortunately, I had already added this during my debugging yesterday. No dice.

Comment: This isn't strictly true.  Chrome will redirect without any Status header being sent to it.  However, if you are using FastCGI, it will send a 200 response code unless you send it the Status pseudoheader, which it does not pass on to the client (e.g. Chrome): http://www.fastcgi.com/docs/faq.html#httpstatus